# not reassigning value after sleep() in php

Tags: php, ubuntu

I need to check and update files if the files are updated on the same day. if it is older, making the script to sleep for some time and again checking the file update time. The issue is the variable which I am using for reassigning the file time is not working. Its holding the older time and not the updated time if the file updated during script running. Please help me !

using filemtime to get file update time.
using while loop to check the time.

Thanks in advance..

thanks for the quick response. Here is the code

```
$current_date=date("Y-m-d 00:00:00");
$file_update_time=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", filemtime("/path/filename"));

while(new DateTime($file_update_time) < new DateTime($current_date))
{
sleep (120);
$file_update_time=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", filemtime("/path/filename"));
}
```

Comment: How about to provide us some code?

Comment: [_"Note: The results of this function are cached. See clearstatcache() for more details."_](http://www.php.net/filemtime) (Reading the manual does wonders.)

Comment: 1) Is `new DateTime` returning something comparable with '<', and 2) will those objects ('new' results) be guaranteed to be garbage collected and not pile up?

Comment: the concept works well, but the only issue is $file_update_time is not getting reassigned after sleep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why `filemtime()` function is always returning the same result is because the result of this function is being cached. See `clearstatcache()` for more details.

No need to mix `date()` function with `Datetime`.

```
while(new DateTime('@'.filemtime('/path/filename')) < new DateTime('today')) {
    sleep(120);
    clearstatcache();
}
```

Comment: hi Glavic, sorry to say that I haven't tried your solution as found another one(running script every 20 mins and update files based on the modified time).. but I planned to try it... will let you know ASAP